# Search half the refID in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table which hold unique REFID (int) and many other columns. I wanted to search a row using the half REFID . So if someone just search **0001** then 50001, 00015... comes up.

I have tried:

```
SELECT TOP 10 REFID     
FROM Tablename
where REFID LIKE '%' + cast(0001 as varchar(10)) +'%'
```

however the problem is, it also giving me 150100 however I wanted **0001** to be in order.

**'0001' is passed in as a parameter** passed in from my C# application. I know I can convert the '0001' to string/varchar before sending it to the SQL however I was looking for a way to do it within the SQL so I can pass in the int from C# application

Comment: What do you mean by *using the half REFID* ??? Which half??

Comment: You want the equivalent of `cast('0001' as varchar(10))` as 0001 === 1

Comment: Try running this: `select cast(0001 as varchar(10))` and what do you get?  That'll give you a clue.

Comment: Hi Alex "cast('0001' as varchar(10)) as 0001 === 1 " makes sense. How would I go about this?

Comment: What results do you expect if 0001 is entered?

Comment: Replace `cast(0001 as varchar(10)` with `'00001'`.

Comment: Something like 50001, 00014, 00001302 and so on.

Comment: We don't know how are you building your SQL statement, so we need more information in order to help. Where do you get your ' 0001' value from? Is it a variable? Is it a parameter in a stored procedure? Is it inside a function in a different programming language?

Comment: OK, you still have to explain some things in your comments, like `00001302`: you would never see that number stored as an integer because integers are not stored with leading zeroes. Left-padding your integer field with leading zeroes up to a ten-digit length would mean that practically every number starting with a 1 below 199,999 will be returned by this filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found:

1. `cast('0001' as varchar(10))` as 0001 === 1 thanks to ALEX K.
2. SQL will strip leading zero and there is no way of keeping the zero if you don't know the length.

My solution: I will send a string from my application and let SQL search it using the string.

Comment: FWIW, ALL of these answers say that.  In fact @jbarker2160's answer said it 2 minutes before alex did.  Be sure to upvote and mark answers for those that helped.

Comment: Alex's comment is what helped me and no other answers helped me.

Comment: Glad you got your answer.  Perhaps now that you're aware of what the issue is, you can re-read these answers and see where you misunderstood.  I'm sure you'll learn something.

Comment: Learning is what it's all about. I really appreciate everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

## Code:

```
SELECT TOP 10 REFID     
FROM Tablename
where REFID LIKE '%0001%'
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  This absolutely works for all of the situations provided by the OP?

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the REFID to a string value (not an int: as the comments point out, `CAST(0001 AS VARCHAR(10))` returns `1`, not `0001`.

```
SELECT TOP 10 REFID     
FROM Tablename
where REFID LIKE '%0001%'
```

EDIT:  you have bigger issues too, like how to search for an integer value stored without leading zeroes, but if you are passing in a parameter you need to either make it varchar, or convert it to varchar in your query body, like so (assuming, of course, that you are always searching for a four-digit string):

`SET @SearchParam_char = RIGHT('000' + CAST(@searchParam_Int AS VARCHAR(10)), 4)`

Comment: Yes, the OP's problem is that `cast(0001 as varchar(10))` evaluates to  `'1'` and not `'0001'` as he wants.

Answer (score 1):

0001 is a number and when converted to varchar() it will become '1'.

This will work with any number but only if you know beforehand that you will use four characters in your expression.

```
SELECT TOP 10 REFID     
FROM Tablename
where REFID LIKE '%' + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(0001 AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) +'%'
```

We don't know how are you building your SQL statement, so we may need more information in order to help. Where do you get your ' 0001' value from? Is it a variable? Is it a parameter in a stored procedure? Is it inside a function in a different programming language?